# How to use plugin's data in a nuxt.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My plugin, env.js:

```js
export default async (_ctx, inject) => {
  const resp = await fetch('/config.json')
  const result = await resp.json()
  inject('env', result)

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('env injected', result)

  return result
}
```

Then an idea was to use it's data inside **nuxt.config.js** to inject into publicRuntimeConfig:

```js
import env from './plugins/env.js'

publicRuntimeConfig: {
  test: env,
},
```

Then in a browser console i'm checking it:

```js
this.$nuxt.$config
```

It shows me:

[image]

instead of a value, though `this.$nuxt.$env` shows the correct values:

[image]

What's wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

Tried Tony's suggestion:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
import axios from 'axios'

export default async () => {
  const resp = await axios.get('/config.json')
  const config = resp.data

  return {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      config
    }
  }
}
```

It cannot fetch **config.json**, but if i point it to an external resource: "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries" it does work.

Intention of this question, is to have **config.json** where a user could simply change variable values there (from a compiled code) and change endpoints without a re-build process.

Answer (score 1):

In `nuxt.config.js`, your `env` variable is a *JavaScript module*, where the default export is the function intended to be automatically run by Nuxt in a plugin's context. Importing the plugin script does not automatically execute that function. Even if you manually ran that function, it wouldn't make sense to use an injected prop as a runtime config because the data is already available as an injected prop.

If you just want to expose `config.json` as a runtime config *instead of* an injected prop, move the code from the plugin into an [async configuration](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration/#asynchronous-configuration):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('/config.json')
  const config = await resp.json()

  return {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      keycloak: config
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, just tried it, but i can't fetch anything, because it it says 'its not defined' here. Then i tried to fetch with axios, its working fine, if i'm getting data from the external resource. But this **config.json** file is placed under "static" dir. So it cannot parse it.

Comment: There's no need to fetch a *local* config file for `nuxt.config.js`. I thought you mightve been fetching a remote file so I didn't comment. For local files, just import the file with: `import config from './config.json'`, after moving the file from `static` to the project root. Then you wouldn't even need an async configuration.

Comment: `nuxt.config.js` is not bundled into the output, so it's not possible to have a dynamic `publicRuntimeConfig`  from a remote resource.

Comment: I see, is there a way to make dynamic runtime config? Right now i see just one way, is to loop over dist/*.html files and replace these env variables.